# Find out which value belongs to which dictionary in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have a list of dicts:

```
list_a = [{'hair_color': 'blonde', 'height': 175, 'weight', 50},
          {'hair_color': 'brunette', 'height': 165, 'weight', 65},
          {'hair_color': 'grey', 'height': 183, 'weight', None}
```

And I get the max value of height:

```
print(max(d.get('height') for d in list_a if d.get('height') is not None))
```

Output: **183**

Let's say I now want to know which hair color is the person whose height is 183. How can I get that?

Comment: `max(list_a, key=lambda d: d['height'])` will give you the entire dict that has the max height.

Comment: @dawg : No, it will raise a TypeError() as there are None types as values for height for some persons in the OP's list_a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the `key` argument to `max` (and `min` and `sort`) comes in handy. Rather than getting a sequence of heights and *then* finding thing maximum height, it lets you find the *item in the list* that *has the maximum height*.

Here's an example:

```
list_a = [{'hair_color': 'blonde', 'height': 175, 'weight', 50},
          {'hair_color': 'brunette', 'height': 165, 'weight', 65},
          {'hair_color': 'grey', 'height': 183, 'weight', None}

tallest_person = max(list_a, key=lambda item:item.get('height', 0))
print(tallest_person)
```

Giving:

```
{'hair_color': 'grey', 'height': 183, 'weight': None}
```

Comment: Can you please share that in a code? I'm still new to Python.

Comment: Ah I see now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the dictionary that contains the value you want from max() or min() like this:

```
def height_key_func (item):
    h = item.get("height", 0) # If "height" is not in the dict, 0 will be used
    # max() must get an object that is comparable with int and/or float:
    if isinstance(h, (int, float)):
        return h
    return 0

person = max(list_a, key=height_key_func)
print (person["hair_color"])
```

To get the dict according to chosen value, you can:

```
def find_by_value (k, v):
    for x in list_a:
        if x[k]==v:
            return x

person = find_by_value("height", 180)
if person is None:
    print("Not found")
```

If you want to find every possible person with same height, then:

```
def find_by_value (k, v):
    persons = []
    for x in list_a:
        if x[k]==v:
            persons.append(x)
    return persons
```

You can search by any value that is equal to request, not only height:

```
def find_by_any_value (v):
    persons = []
    for x in list_a:
        if v in x.values():
            persons.append(x)
    return persons
```

Lastly, you can shorten this up like:

```
def find_by_value (k, v):
    return [x for x in list_a if x[k]==v]

persons = find_by_value("height", 180)
```